# SASI index in Cassandra and How it differs from normal indexing

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I started using ***SASI indexing*** and used the following setup,

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id int,
    lastname text,
    firstname text,
    dateofbirth date,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, lastname, firstname)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (lastname ASC, firstname ASC));

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX employee_firstname_idx ON employee (firstname) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.StandardAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};
```

I perform the following query,

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE firstname like '%s';
```

As per my study, It seems the same as normal secondary indexing in Cassandra, Except providing the ***LIKE*** search,

1) Could somebody explain how it differs from normal secondary index in Cassandra?
2) What are the best configurations like mode, analyzer_class and case_sensitive - Any recommended documentation for this?

Comment: Unrelated comment - for query, it's better to use prepared queries instead of building query per individual parameter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*1) Could somebody explain how it differs from normal secondary index in Cassandra?*

Normal secondary index is essentially another lookup table comprising secondary index columns & primary key. Hence it has its own set of sstable files (disk), memtable (memory) and write overhead (cpu).

SASI was an improvement open sourced (contributed by Apple) to Cassandra community. This index gets created for every SSTable being flushed to disk and doesn't maintain a separate table. Hence less disk usage, no separate memtable/bloom filter/partition index (less memory) and minimal overhead.

*2) What are the best configurations like mode, analyzer_class and case_sensitive - Any recommended documentation for this?*

Configuration depends on your use case :-

Essentially there are three modes

1. PREFIX - Used to serve LIKE queries based on prefix of indexed column
2. CONTAINS - Used to serve LIKE queries based on whether the search term exists in the indexed column
3. SPARSE - Used to index data that is sparse (every term/column value has less than 5 matching keys). For example range queries that span large timestamps.

Analyzer_class : Analyzers can be specified that will analyze the text in the specified column.

1. The **NonTokenizingAnalyzer** is used for cases where the text is not analyzed, but case normalization or sensitivity is required.
2. The **StandardAnalyzer** is used for analysis that involves stemming, case normalization, case sensitivity, skipping common words like "and" and "the", and localization of the language used to complete the analysis

case_sensitive : As name implies, whether the indexed column should be searched case insensitive. Applicable values are

1. True
2. False

Detailed documentation reference [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndexConcept.html) and detailed blog post on [performance](http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2058#sasi_perf_benchmarks).

Comment: SASI has its own SStable attached indexing so provides less disk usage and less overhead, How it actually differs in query performance? Could you mention the workflow?

Comment: Would highly recommend going through this blog http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2058#sasi_perf_benchmarks

Comment: Also I understand, the value is the key for the secondary index table and its value is the primary key, How the disk index for SASI table is defined?

Comment: The values form a Btree index in case of SASI. So the value directly points to the data in the sstable, skipping bloom filter, partition index.

Comment: So If I have a value like 'Australia' and I index this country column, Does it form a search string like A, AU, AUS, AUST etc., in all combination and map to the SSTable?

Comment: Also If I specify the partition key, Will there be an advantage in using SASI like native secondary index

Comment: @Harry I believe I have provided the solution for your original question. Please remember to accept/upvote the answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 5):

Here is a short summary of SASI from https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/wiki/Indexing-in-Cassandra-3:

SASI (acroynym of "SStable-Attached Secondary Indexing") is a reimplementation of the classic Cassandra secondary indexing with one main goal in mind - efficiently support more sophisticated search queries such as:

- AND or OR combinations of queries.
- Wildcard search in string values.
- Range queries.
- Lucene-inspired word search in string values (including word breaking, capitalization normalization, stemming, etc., as determined by a user-given "Analyzer").

Some of these things were already possible with secondary index, but inefficient, because required getting a long list of partitions, reading them (requiring inefficient seeks to each one) and filtering on them. SASI implement them using a new on-disk format based on B+ trees, and does not reuse regular Cassandra column families or sstables like the classic Secondary Indexing method did.

SASI attaches to each sstable its own immutable index file (and hence the name of this method), and also attaches an index to each memtable. During compaction, the indexes of the files being compacted together are also compacted to create one new index.